# Restoring all mysql databases from old xampp server to new installation

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore database from old **xampp** server to newly installed version through copying folder between ***xampp/mysql/*** data folders, I did all the steps that I got from here and also google but the problem is that database did not restore completely only tables is restored, stored procedures, functions is still missing.

any one faced or solved like that issue?
help

Comment: the question you mentioned doesn't totally relate to my issue 

Comment: copying fles works only if the version are equal and you copy **all** files. You can try to restore the databse from the files or you have your old system running again and mysqldump the databases